# Creating a Client Socket in java with remote address is in Inet4Address format and bind address is in Inet6Address format

Tags: sockets, ipv6

Creating a ClientSocket program as below:

```
    String remote_host = "10.0.0.1";
    int remote_port = 9990;
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(remote_host);//It gets a Inet4Address
    String bindhost="facade";
    InetAddress bindaddress = InetAddress.getByName(bindhost);//It gets a Inet6Address   as Ipv6 address is configured for hostname "facade" in /etc/hosts
    socket = new Socket(address, remote_port,bindaddress,9787);
```

Getting exception as below:

```
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:276)
    at Client.main(Client.java:25)
```

Can we create the socket in the above manner ???

Tried ssh protocol using similar way.Was getting the same error :
[root@mysystem ~]# ssh -6 -b facade  root@10.0.0.1
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.1 port 22: Network is unreachable

//facade is configured with ipv6 address in /etc/hosts

Comment: You can't connect to an IPv4 address via IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last two arguments to 'new Socket(...)'. You don't need to specify a local address or port. TCP will find both for you.

Comment: In my case i need to use the local address and port.We deploy the module across multiple nodes.At any point of time a virtual ip is created on any of these nodes and connection to external system should go from this local ip & port(virtual ip)